# Inkscape export to pdf objects are missing

Tags: inkscape, pdf

I am using inkscape to export a svg-file I have created with it to pdf.
Everything works fine, except for the rectangular elements which are missing in the pdf file.

[image]

My svg file can be found here: [file from cloud-drive](https://www.amazon.de/clouddrive/share/kRyEqXLZVLTATyLET0phYXymBHXmFKpZkLf9WnaOYEo)

I already tried to ungroup all the elements and change some directions, but the problem remains.
Is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by myself:

Every object that you want needs a border. If someone does not want to have a border for an element, it is possible to set it to zero width.

Comment: Hmmm . . . that shouldn't really be a problem.  I just tried creating a PDF from an SVG containing a filled rectangle with no stroke, and it works just fine. I suspect something else is going on here. I've tried to investigate by checking your SVG file, but can't find the culprit. One strange thing about your SVG is that it has no layers.  How did you get this graphic into Inkscape?  Was it created from scratch inside Inkscape, or copy pasted from somewhere, or was it created by other software?